# Add user to group error - Code

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jsom

I am getting an error when trying to add a user to group in JavaScript, here is my code below:

```
    user = web.ensureUser("domain\\natalie");
    membersGroup = web.get_siteGroups().getByName("site Members");
    membersGroup.get_users().add(user);
    userCollection = membersGroup.get_users();

    context.load(user);
    context.load(membersGroup);
    context.load(userCollection);
    context.executeQueryAsync(_onUserSucceed, _onFail);
```

I am getting the error: The parameter loginName cannot be empty or bigger than 251 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine, but how did you put the domain name? Was it domain\natalie? Sometimes you need to make it like: domain.local to make it work or domain.[value] depending on your environment. The thing is that you have to fully qualify it when it's needed.